# subir archivos con laravel a una carpeta del servidor

Tags: php, laravel-8

tengo una parte de mi sistema donde subo un archivo excel a una ruta de mi servidor, esto funcionaba perfecto, pero ahora me comenzó a dar errores de permisos, me muestra el siguiente error:
Unable to write in the "C:\laragon\www\cga-app\public/archivos/" directory.

esto me pasa en mi servidor de pruebas, en el de producción funciona sin problemas.
Espero me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Sencillamente debe ajustar los permisos de la carpeta archivos, para que pueda escribir ahí. por ftp, click derecho , propiedades y ahí darle check a write.